# How to migrate Azure Service Principal to MS Graph from AAD graph?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a service principal created in Azure that is being used in Azure DevOps as a Service Connection.
Now the cloud team has flagged the said Service Principal as still using AAD Graph. We need to migrate to MS Graph as Azure is deprecation AAD Graph.

I have checked the API Permissions on the Service Principal and it uses Microsoft Graph API.
The agents in the Agent Pool under DevOps all have been updated to the latest version 3.220.5

What else do I need to do to make sure the dependency on AAD graph is removed and it only uses MS Graph?